# Using polymorphism generics in an ovverriden method

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, overriding

Hy guys,

I have a question about using generics with polymorphic method. Basically this is my situation:

I have a factory that depends of the parameter, instantiate respectively two classes:

**CSVParsingBuilder.java** or **XMLParsingBuilder.java**, I will show just the CSV case bacause will be the same for XML.

**CSVParsingBuilder.java**

```
class CSVParsingBuilder<T> implements IParsableBuilder<T>{

    CSVCriteriaBuilder<T> criteriaBuilder;

    @Override
    public void setCriteria(CSVCriteriaBuilder<T> criteriaBuilder) {
        this.criteriaBuilder=criteriaBuilder;
    }

    @Override
    public IParsableImp<T> buildStrategy() {
        if (criteriaBuilder == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("you have to specify a criteria builder");
        }
        return new CSVParsingImpl<T>(this);
    }


    public ICriteriaBuilder<T> getCriteriaBuilder() {
        return criteriaBuilder;
    }
}
```

**CSVCriteriaBuilder.java**

```
public class CSVCriteriaBuilder<T> implements ICriteriaBuilder<T>{....}
```

**IParsableBuilder.java**

```
public interface IParsableBuilder<T> {

    public IParsableImp<T> buildStrategy();
    public void setCriteria(ICriteriaBuilder<T> criteriaBuilder);
}
```

Now the compiler complaining me because the `setCriteria` call is using a subclass of `ICriteriaBuilder` like argument and so I can't use correctly the `@Override` annotation.

I would like just to know if would be possible change signature of the `setCriteria` method  in the `IParsableBuilder` interface, just to accept any argument that extends ICriteriaBuilder, something like this:

**IParsableBuilder.java**

```
public interface IParsableBuilder<T> {

    public IParsableImp<T> buildStrategy();
    public void setCriteria(? extends ICriteriaBuilder<T> criteriaBuilder);
}
```

Could someone help about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to introduce one more type parameter for that to work:

```
public interface IParsableBuilder<T, S extends ICriteriaBuilder<T>> {

    public IParsableImp<T> buildStrategy();
    public void setCriteria(S criteriaBuilder);
}
```

And then implement it as:

```
class CSVParsingBuilder<T> implements IParsableBuilder<T, CSVCriteriaBuilder<T>>{

    CSVCriteriaBuilder<T> criteriaBuilder;

    @Override
    public void setCriteria(CSVCriteriaBuilder<T> criteriaBuilder) {
        this.criteriaBuilder=criteriaBuilder;
    }
    ....
}
```

It would work this way. I don't think it would be possible otherwise. The reason being, method overriding with covariant return type is allowed, but with covariant formal parameter type is not allowed.